how to write a regex for the oniguruma that would catch a line only if there is no certain substring on its left?
i am trying to write a syntax support for a proprietary language for vs code and it relies on oniguruma. i am trying to write two regexes: for  begin and end.
the code looks like that:
public sub myNewSub(arg1:string;arg2:integer);
var
 var1: Integer;
begin
 var1:=0;
end sub myNewSub

i am trying to catch a part from the first line (sub) and a part from the last line (end sub ...)
i wrote a regex for end and it looks like
(?i)\b(\s*end\s* sub)\s*([_a-z][0-9_a-z]*)\s*;

now i need a regex for start, and the problem is that i need to figure out how to spot 'end' at the start of a string. i tried negative lookback but there was a problem with not allowed quantifier
(?<!end\s*)sub

example:
input:
sub mysub1; 
  var i:Integer; 
  sub innersub1; 
    begin; 
  end sub innersub1; 
begin
end sub mysub1;

desired output:
match 1: lines from mysub1 to end mysub1
match 2: lines from innersub1 to end innersub1

Why is this tagged perl?

As I know oniguruma is similar to PCRE1 -- Perl Compatible Regular Expressions

@jenny03 what is your expected output of regex matching ? please clarify in your question

Please re-read the notes for the tag.

In Perl, I would use a regex match that looks for a line that contains sub, followed by lines that don't start with end, followed by a line that starts with end. With the m and x flags but without the s flag, the pattern would be ^ .* \b sub \b .* \n (?: (?! end \b ) .* \n )* end \b .* \n?

@jenny03, Perl, PCRE and oniguruma are all different things.
